# Pass HTML data attribute to a Semantic UI modal

Tags: jquery, html, modal-dialog, custom-data-attribute, semantic-ui

I have a list of items, each with a different data type, that when clicked I want to pass the data-type="name" as a variable to a Semantic UI modal.

```
<a class="segment__item u-cf" id="modal" data-type="name">
    ...
</a>
```

I can trigger the modal fine on click

```
$('#modal-newpage')
    .modal('attach events', '#newpage', 'show')
    .modal('setting', 'duration', 280)
    .modal('setting', 'closable', false);
```

However, I want to use the same modal for all items (with title as data-type "name") without creating multiple modal instances and I'm not sure how to pass the data to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data-type` is not supposed to change all the time... I would use a hidden `input` in the modal to take care of changing values:

HTML:

```
<div id="modal" class="ui modal">
  <input class="type" type="hidden">
  ...
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#modal input.type').val('name');
  $('#modal').modal('show');
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you, only got a chance to work on it today. That's really helped.

Answer (score 0):

The question has been answered by @wafield. However, heres a more detailed explanation if it helps anyone else:

```
$('.segment__item').click(function() {
    $pagetype = $(this).data('type');
    $('#modal-newpage')
        .modal('show')
        .modal('setting', 'duration', 280)
        .modal('setting', 'closable', false);
    $('h1.modal__title').text("New " + $pagetype + " page");
    $('form').attr('action', $('form').attr('action') + $pagetype);
    $('input[name=page_type]').val($pagetype);
});
```